# Автоматический перенос элементов в CSS grid как при float или inline-block

Tags: css, css-grid

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать на гриде следующее поведение, бывшее элементарным без грида.

Есть родительский блок с `display: grid`. Мы не знаем, сколько в нём будет дочерних элементов, сколько столбцов и рядов.

Далее в него добавляются элементы шириной и высотой 100px. Их ширина не тянется, а остаётся 100px. То есть элементы сами заведуют своей шириной. Они располагаются горизонтально друг за другом. При достижении правого края, если элемент не влезает в оставшееся пустое место контентной области родителя, он должен расположиться на новом горизонтальном ряду. Как это было раньше при вёрстке на флоатах.

При этом если родитель меняется по ширине, или если сами элементы изменились по ширине, то элементы должны просто перестроиться, с той же логикой переносов на новые строки.

Например `grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, 100px )` весьма хорош, но при этом не выполняется "элементы сами заведуют своей шириной".

Вот диаграмма с ожидаемым поведением:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Разве не оно?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.container>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Или ширина дочерних элементов может быть разной? В этом дело?

Comment: Задайте второму элементу ширину 250px, увидите, что она наезжает на третий элемент.

Comment: Да. У меня элементы могут быть разными в зависимости от того, что в них внутри отображается. Скрипт им ставит разные ширины. А гриды вместо старых способов нужны для плюшек вроде gap, равномерной сетки и так далее.

Comment: Используйте просто gap, оно работает на flex. Но насчет поддержки не знаю. А так вообще интересно решение на гридах.

Comment: @OliverPatterson на данный момент у гэпа для флексов плохая поддержка судя по кэн ай юз - https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap